# Viewing integration as a $\mathbb{Z}$ action on function spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, integration, derivatives, group-actions

Note: This question has been edited thanks to a comment by Chris Culter. Thank you for this comment.

### The question:

I was fooling around and thought of a perspective which i thought to be quite curious:

Consider the space $X = C^\infty(\mathbb{R})/\{\textrm{polynomials}\}$, quotiented via addition (quotient is a quotient of abelian groups and not rings). Given $\bar{f} \in X$, we may lift it to a $C^\infty$ function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we define $(\int)^n \bar{f}$ to be:

(1) For $n$ positive, the integral $\overline{\int \int ... \int f}$, ($n$ times).

(2) For $n \le 0$, $\overline{\textrm{the $n$'th derivative of $f$}}$.

One can check that this is well defined on the quotient space, and:

Then, one can easily see that $\int^{m+n}\bar{f} = \int^n (\int^m \bar{f})$, and $\int^0 \bar{f} = \bar{f}$. Thus, we see that $n \mapsto \int^n$ defines a $\mathbb{Z}$ action on $X$.

Questions:

(1) Has anybody come across this perspective? Is this perspective useful?

(2) One question one might ask about this is what are the orbits (and finite orbits). For example, $\{ \sin, \cos, -\sin, -\cos \}$ is an interesting orbit of size $4$. Can anyone think of some nice results along these lines?

---

Comment: A technical issue: In order for $\int^n\int^{-n}f=f$, you have to collapse all polynomials to be equal in your function space. So instead of acting on $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, you're acting on the quotient space $C^\infty(\mathbb R)/\mathbb R[x]$. This probably isn't a big problem, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: Consider the constant function $f(x)=79$. Then $\int^{-1}f=0$, and by (1), we get $\int\int^{-1}f=0$. But $f\neq0$.

Comment: Okay, consider the linear function $f(x)=42x$. What is $\int^{-1}f$?

Answer (score -1):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is amenable so we have:
Fixed-point property. Any action of the group by continuous affine transformations on a compact convex subset of a (separable) locally convex topological vector space has a fixed point. For locally compact abelian groups, this property is satisfied as a result of the Markov–Kakutani fixed-point theorem.
This might be interesting

Comment: give me a a little time to digest this please.

Comment: Can the person who downvoted this please explain why they downvoted it so that we can better understand what you find to be wrong or not useful?

Comment: A fixed point is just a point where $\frac{df}{dx} = f$. But then this ODE has only solutions $f(x) = Ae^x$.

Comment: This action that i described is indeed linear because, $\int^n (f+g) = \int^n(f) + \int^n(g)$, and therefore, is, in particular, affine. So this hypothesis of the theorem is true. What your theorem would be telling us is that every compact convex subset of a locally compact convex subspace of $X = C^\infty(\mathbb{R})/\{\textrm{polynomials}\}$ must contain an exponential map. This strikes me as as a quite strange result, dont you think? (What is special about the exponential map in connection with the topology? Why should it be given a special standing?)